# Logarithmic Inequality and quadratic function

Tags: logarithms

Prove that if $m$ satisfy inequality: $$\left (1+ \frac{1}{2m}\right) \log_k 3 - \log_k (27 + 3^\frac{1}{2m}) \le 2$$
where $k=\frac{1}{2}$, then $x^2 + mx + 1  > 0$ for every real number.
I solved one $m_1=0$, but the other doesn't satisfy the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have $$\left (1+ \frac{1}{2m}\right) \log_k x - \log_k (27 + 3^\frac{1}{2m}) \le 2\iff\log_k\frac{x^{1+\frac{1}{2m}}}{27+ 3^{\frac{1}{2m}}}\le2=\log_k\frac14$$
and because the log is injective and increasing we get
$$\frac{x^{1+\frac{1}{2m}}}{27+ 3^{\frac{1}{2m}}}\lt\frac14$$ Now you can work in an easier way.Try it and if you can't finish I shall give you the final part.

Comment: Gosh I'm sorry, I made a mistake. $x$ should be just $3$. Btw I got to the point you're talking about, but solving in farther is getting me to one $m_2$ which doesn't satisfy the second condition

Comment: With $3$ instead of $x$ the problem becomes easier to answer. I don't need anymore the final part I expected give you. Regards.

Comment: It's my homework for tommorrow, I can't see how it's easier now. Could help me more? :/